# Double.compare() giving inconsistent results

Tags: android, double, listadapter

I have a custom ListAdapter for displaying a series of numbers. Within the getView() method I attempt to set the background colour of a TextView based on the difference between two numbers:

```
if (Double.compare(homeDT, homeBF) > 0) {
homeDiff.setBackgroundResource(color.holo_blue_light);
}
```

This should set the TextView background to light blue if homeBF > homeDT, only sometimes it makes the background light blue when homeBF < homeDT. It appears to happen randomly to one or two child views within the ListView.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you take in consideration the recycling of the row views? Do you revert the background of the `homeDiff` to the default if `homeDT<= homeBF`?

Comment: probably related to listview row recycling. add an else clause to set the bg back to its original value

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't consider the view recycling. A simple else clause solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (HomeDT > HomeBF){
// What you want to do if HomeDT is greater than HomeBF
}
else {
// What you want to do if HomeDT is not greater than HomeBF
}
```